# Airflow between two rooms (one hot, one cold)

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, flow, air

Scenario —

It is night time and somewhat cold outside.

Room 1 (Bedroom): The window is slightly creaked open. I have a space heater going on continually heating room 1. One door is closed to the outside hallway, another door is closed to the bedroom bathroom (the bathroom and hallway do not share a door). Room 1 is getting hotter due to the heater.

Room 2 (Bathroom): The window is wide open. The room is getting colder from the outside air. The only door, which is to the bedroom, is closed but there is still a relatively considerable slit under the bathroom door for air to travel through.

———————

Note: Obviously to know for sure we need measurements, but assume the temperature difference is great enough to create airflow between the hot and cold room.

——————-

Question 1… will the hot air from the bedroom flow into the cold bathroom? Is having the window of room 1 slightly open necessary so that there is new air to pull from to maintain airflow?

Follow up question… if there is a bunch of bleach on the carpet of the main bedroom, will the airflow cause any bleach particles to leave through the opening under the door to the bathroom? If I am sleeping on an elevated bed, would the bleach particles not rise but rather flow out through the slit in the bathroom door? How would you imagine the airflow working?